# Can't select a number from MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get  a value from database and echo it. It seems I mixed something wrong, so at the moment just no value appears.

```
$postamount=$db->prepare("SELECT post_amount FROM users WHERE id = ? ");
$postamount->bind_param('s',$_SESSION['id']);
$postamount->execute();
$fsvsfnvdjn= mysqli_fetch_assoc($postamount);
$fvklnsfvnfv=implode($fsvsfnvdjn);
echo($fvklnsfvnfv);
```

Such warning appear in the log:

```
 mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pageok.php on line 25
  implode(): Argument must be an array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pageok.php on line 26
```

Can you explain please, how to do this right?

Comment: You need to execute before you fetch.

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['id']` a string?

Comment: @JayBlanchard didn't help

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers int

Comment: Then why are you binding it as a string?, `s` is for strings, `i` is for integers.

Comment: As Jay already said, you need to execute the statement! You replied "Didn't help", but your code does not reflect that you updated accordingly...

Comment: Variables like `$fsvsfnvdjn` and `$fvklnsfvnfv` do not really help matters. And yes, please do edit your question with what you tried from Jay's suggestion - "didn't help" is not a sufficient response, and gives us no further hints to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your script with the following

```
$postamount=$db->prepare("SELECT post_amount FROM users WHERE id = ? ");
$postamount->bind_param('s',$_SESSION['id']);
$postamount->execute();
$result = $postamount->get_result();
$arr = array();
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[]=$row["post_amount"];
    }
$str=implode($arr);
echo($str);
```